# Django Restful: How do I update my custom user model?

Tags: django, django-rest-framework, serialization

I'm building an API as part of a project for university, However, I have become stuck when working out how to make updates to my custom user model. At present I have a serializer for updating the profile, but when I try to update the table using the serializer, it falls over with  error 1406: "Data too long for column 'title' at row 1". I'm not sure how to resolve this at present and was wondering if someone could point me in the right direction

*update:*
So it seems that I was getting the Data too long for column errors because The code I have is appending to the columns instead of just either altering them if the JSON contains data for the field, or leaving them if it does not. So once I'd tinkered with column lengths I was getting the following database row:

> (None, 'Anthony'),    (None, (None, 'Anthony')),  1,  0,  1,  1,  2019-01-01, ('a
>   test address', 'hello'),  (None, None),   (None, None),   edd,    (None,
>   'boy'),   (None, 'there'),    (None, None),   (None, '282')

**model in question:**

```
class User(AbstractBaseUser, PermissionsMixin):
    email = models.EmailField(_('email address'), unique=True)
    title =models.CharField(_('Title'), max_length=8, null=True,  blank=True)
    first_name=models.CharField(_('first name(s)'), max_length=100, blank =True)
    last_name=models.CharField(_('last name'), max_length=100, blank = True)
    is_active=models.BooleanField(_('account active'), default=False)
    is_driver = models.BooleanField(_('driver status'), default=False)
    is_staff = models.BooleanField(_('staff status'), default =False)
    is_admin = models.BooleanField(_('admin status'), default =False)

    dob = models.DateField(auto_now_add= True, blank=True)
    address_1=models.CharField(_('address line 1'),max_length=60, null=False, blank=False)
    address_2=models.CharField(_('address line 2'),max_length=60, null=True, blank=True)
    address_3=models.CharField(_('address line 3'),max_length=60, null=True, blank=True)
    city = models.CharField(_('city'),max_length=60, null=False, blank=False)
    county = models.CharField(_('county'),max_length=60, null=False, blank=False)
    postcode = models.CharField(_('postcode'),max_length=8, blank=False, null=False)
    phone_no = models.CharField(_('phone number'),max_length=50, null=True, blank=True)
    mobile_no = models.CharField(_('mobile Number'),max_length=50,null=False, blank=False)
    drivers_licence_number = models.CharField(max_length=30, null=True, blank=True)
    taxi_licence_number=models.CharField(max_length=30, null=True, blank=True)
    driver_photo=models.ImageField(blank=True)
    date_joined=models.DateField(auto_now_add=True, blank=True)
    last_update=models.DateField(auto_now_add=True, blank=True)
```

**serializer in question:**

```
class UserProfileSerializer (serializers.ModelSerializer):
    model = User

    id = serializers.IntegerField(read_only=True)
    dob = serializers.DateField(read_only=True)
    title=serializers.CharField(max_length=8, required=False)
    first_name=serializers.CharField(max_length=80,required=False)
    last_name=serializers.CharField(max_length=80,required=False)
    address_1 = serializers.CharField(max_length=100, required=False)
    address_2 = serializers.CharField(max_length=100,required=False)
    address_3 = serializers.CharField(max_length=100,required=False)
    postcode = serializers.CharField(max_length=10, required=False)
    county = serializers.CharField(max_length=50, required=False)
    city = serializers.CharField(max_length=50, required=False)
    phone_no = serializers.CharField(required=False)
    mobile_no = serializers.CharField(required=False)




    def update (self, instance, validated_data):
        instance.title= validated_data.get('title'), instance.title
        instance.first_name = validated_data.get('first_name'), instance.first_name
        instance.last_name = validated_data.get('last_name'), instance.first_name
        instance.address_1 = validated_data.get('address_1'), instance.address_1
        instance.address_2 = validated_data.get('address_2'), instance.address_2
        instance.address_3 = validated_data.get('address_3'), instance.address_3
        instance.postcode = validated_data.get('postcode'), instance.postcode
        instance.county = validated_data.get('county'), instance.county
        instance.phone_no = validated_data.get('phone_no'),instance.phone_no
        instance.mobile_no = validated_data.get('mobile_no'), instance.mobile_no
        instance.last_update = datetime.now()

        instance.save()
    return instance
```

**View in question:**

```
class UpdateProfile(APIView):
    permission_classes=[permissions.IsAuthenticated]

    def post(self, request, format=None):

        user=request.user
        print (user.id)
        query_set=User.objects.get(id=user.id)
        print("we got a queryset")
        print(query_set)

        serializer=UserProfileSerializer(query_set, data=request.data)


        if serializer.is_valid():

            profile = serializer.save()

            if profile:        
                return Response(user.data, status=status.HTTP_200_OK)

        else:
            return Response(serializer.errors, status=status.HTTP_400_BAD_REQUEST)
```

**Trace from the server console:**

> Internal Server Error: /editprofile/ Traceback (most recent call
>   last):   File
>   "C:\Users\clini\MYDOCU~1\LICLIP~1\NET302~1\lib\site-packages\django\db\backends\utils.py",
>   line 85, in _execute
>       return self.cursor.execute(sql, params)   File "C:\Users\clini\MYDOCU~1\LICLIP~1\NET302~1\lib\site-packages\django\db\backends\mysql\base.py",
>   line 71, in execute
>       return self.cursor.execute(query, args)   File "C:\Users\clini\MYDOCU~1\LICLIP~1\NET302~1\lib\site-packages\MySQLdb\cursors.py",
>   line 250, in execute
>       self.errorhandler(self, exc, value)   File "C:\Users\clini\MYDOCU~1\LICLIP~1\NET302~1\lib\site-packages\MySQLdb\connections.py",
>   line 50, in defaulterrorhandler
>       raise errorvalue   File "C:\Users\clini\MYDOCU~1\LICLIP~1\NET302~1\lib\site-packages\MySQLdb\cursors.py",
>   line 247, in execute
>       res = self._query(query)   File "C:\Users\clini\MYDOCU~1\LICLIP~1\NET302~1\lib\site-packages\MySQLdb\cursors.py",
>   line 412, in _query
>       rowcount = self._do_query(q)   File "C:\Users\clini\MYDOCU~1\LICLIP~1\NET302~1\lib\site-packages\MySQLdb\cursors.py",
>   line 375, in _do_query
>       db.query(q)   File "C:\Users\clini\MYDOCU~1\LICLIP~1\NET302~1\lib\site-packages\MySQLdb\connections.py",
>   line 276, in query
>       _mysql.connection.query(self, query)
>   _mysql_exceptions.DataError: (1406, "Data too long for column 'title' at row 1")
>
> The above exception was the direct cause of the following exception:
>
> Traceback (most recent call last):   File
>   "C:\Users\clini\MYDOCU~1\LICLIP~1\NET302~1\lib\site-packages\django\core\handlers\exception.py",
>   line 34, in inner
>       response = get_response(request)   File "C:\Users\clini\MYDOCU~1\LICLIP~1\NET302~1\lib\site-packages\django\core\handlers\base.py",
>   line 126, in _get_response
>       response = self.process_exception_by_middleware(e, request)   File "C:\Users\clini\MYDOCU~1\LICLIP~1\NET302~1\lib\site-packages\django\core\handlers\base.py",
>   line 124, in _get_response
>       response = wrapped_callback(request, *callback_args, **callback_kwargs)   File "C:\Users\clini\MYDOCU~1\LICLIP~1\NET302~1\lib\site-packages\django\views\decorators\csrf.py",
>   line 54, in wrapped_view
>       return view_func(*args, **kwargs)   File "C:\Users\clini\MYDOCU~1\LICLIP~1\NET302~1\lib\site-packages\django\views\generic\base.py",
>   line 68, in view
>       return self.dispatch(request, *args, **kwargs)   File "C:\Users\clini\MYDOCU~1\LICLIP~1\NET302~1\lib\site-packages\rest_framework\views.py",
>   line 495, in dispatch
>       response = self.handle_exception(exc)   File "C:\Users\clini\MYDOCU~1\LICLIP~1\NET302~1\lib\site-packages\rest_framework\views.py",
>   line 455, in handle_exception
>       self.raise_uncaught_exception(exc)   File "C:\Users\clini\MYDOCU~1\LICLIP~1\NET302~1\lib\site-packages\rest_framework\views.py",
>   line 492, in dispatch
>       response = handler(request, *args, **kwargs)   File "C:\Users\clini\git\net302API\Test1\api\views.py", line 68, in post
>       profile = serializer.save()   File "C:\Users\clini\MYDOCU~1\LICLIP~1\NET302~1\lib\site-packages\rest_framework\serializers.py",
>   line 209, in save
>       self.instance = self.update(self.instance, validated_data)   File "C:\Users\clini\git\net302API\Test1\api\serializers.py", line 137, in
>   update
>       instance.save()   File "C:\Users\clini\MYDOCU~1\LICLIP~1\NET302~1\lib\site-packages\django\contrib\auth\base_user.py",
>   line 73, in save
>       super().save(*args, **kwargs)   File "C:\Users\clini\MYDOCU~1\LICLIP~1\NET302~1\lib\site-packages\django\db\models\base.py",
>   line 718, in save
>       force_update=force_update, update_fields=update_fields)   File "C:\Users\clini\MYDOCU~1\LICLIP~1\NET302~1\lib\site-packages\django\db\models\base.py",
>   line 748, in save_base
>       updated = self._save_table(raw, cls, force_insert, force_update, using, update_fields)   File
>   "C:\Users\clini\MYDOCU~1\LICLIP~1\NET302~1\lib\site-packages\django\db\models\base.py",
>   line 812, in _save_table
>       forced_update)   File "C:\Users\clini\MYDOCU~1\LICLIP~1\NET302~1\lib\site-packages\django\db\models\base.py",
>   line 861, in _do_update
>       return filtered._update(values) > 0   File "C:\Users\clini\MYDOCU~1\LICLIP~1\NET302~1\lib\site-packages\django\db\models\query.py",
>   line 712, in _update
>       return query.get_compiler(self.db).execute_sql(CURSOR)   File "C:\Users\clini\MYDOCU~1\LICLIP~1\NET302~1\lib\site-packages\django\db\models\sql\compiler.py",
>   line 1383, in execute_sql
>       cursor = super().execute_sql(result_type)   File "C:\Users\clini\MYDOCU~1\LICLIP~1\NET302~1\lib\site-packages\django\db\models\sql\compiler.py",
>   line 1065, in execute_sql
>       cursor.execute(sql, params)   File "C:\Users\clini\MYDOCU~1\LICLIP~1\NET302~1\lib\site-packages\django\db\backends\utils.py",
>   line 100, in execute
>       return super().execute(sql, params)   File "C:\Users\clini\MYDOCU~1\LICLIP~1\NET302~1\lib\site-packages\django\db\backends\utils.py",
>   line 68, in execute
>       return self._execute_with_wrappers(sql, params, many=False, executor=self._execute)   File
>   "C:\Users\clini\MYDOCU~1\LICLIP~1\NET302~1\lib\site-packages\django\db\backends\utils.py",
>   line 77, in _execute_with_wrappers
>       return executor(sql, params, many, context)   File "C:\Users\clini\MYDOCU~1\LICLIP~1\NET302~1\lib\site-packages\django\db\backends\utils.py",
>   line 85, in _execute
>       return self.cursor.execute(sql, params)   File "C:\Users\clini\MYDOCU~1\LICLIP~1\NET302~1\lib\site-packages\django\db\utils.py",
>   line 89, in **exit**
>       raise dj_exc_value.with_traceback(traceback) from exc_value   File "C:\Users\clini\MYDOCU~1\LICLIP~1\NET302~1\lib\site-packages\django\db\backends\utils.py",
>   line 85, in _execute
>       return self.cursor.execute(sql, params)   File "C:\Users\clini\MYDOCU~1\LICLIP~1\NET302~1\lib\site-packages\django\db\backends\mysql\base.py",
>   line 71, in execute
>       return self.cursor.execute(query, args)   File "C:\Users\clini\MYDOCU~1\LICLIP~1\NET302~1\lib\site-packages\MySQLdb\cursors.py",
>   line 250, in execute
>       self.errorhandler(self, exc, value)   File "C:\Users\clini\MYDOCU~1\LICLIP~1\NET302~1\lib\site-packages\MySQLdb\connections.py",
>   line 50, in defaulterrorhandler
>       raise errorvalue   File "C:\Users\clini\MYDOCU~1\LICLIP~1\NET302~1\lib\site-packages\MySQLdb\cursors.py",
>   line 247, in execute
>       res = self._query(query)   File "C:\Users\clini\MYDOCU~1\LICLIP~1\NET302~1\lib\site-packages\MySQLdb\cursors.py",
>   line 412, in _query
>       rowcount = self._do_query(q)   File "C:\Users\clini\MYDOCU~1\LICLIP~1\NET302~1\lib\site-packages\MySQLdb\cursors.py",
>   line 375, in _do_query
>       db.query(q)   File "C:\Users\clini\MYDOCU~1\LICLIP~1\NET302~1\lib\site-packages\MySQLdb\connections.py",
>   line 276, in query
>       _mysql.connection.query(self, query) django.db.utils.DataError: (1406, "Data too long for column 'title' at row 1")

Comment: looks like you are setting too long `title` - here you are setting it only to **8** symbols: `title =models.CharField(_('Title'), max_length=8, null=True,  blank=True)`

Comment: I thought this might be the case, but when I pass the code a value for title that is only 3-4 symbols, it throws the same error.

Comment: did u try to make `title` blank? show full error trace.

Comment: Remove the print statement and use a third party app to debug your app

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So To close this issue down, I found the solution. When I wrote the update method for my serializer i was writing them as 
`instance.fieldname =validated.data.get('input_name'),instance.fieldname`

When they should have been 
`instance.fieldname =validated.data.get('input_name',instance.fieldname)`

Thank you all for the help :)

Answer (score 0):

Did you maybe update the max_length of the title and did not migrate yet?

Comment: Okay. I tried that and it works, kind of. It moves data to the database, but instead of just getting "string of input data" or "same data as previously" I'm getting


(None, 'Anthony') (None, (None, 'Anthony')) 1 0 1 1 2019-01-01 ('a test address', 'hello') (None, None) (None, None) edd (None, 'boy') (None, 'there') (None, None) (None, '282')